# Strange behavior of smart diagram with \resizebox

Tags: boxes, smartdiagram

I'm working with package smartdiagram.  Since I can't specify the width of the diagram (or can I...?), I'm using `\resizebox` as a workaround.  This strategy works fine EXCEPT when I set custom colors (`\setcolorbox...`).  How does trying to change the color cause all this strange behavior (see the image), and what can I do to fix it?

MWE:

[image: smartdiagram example]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\resizebox{.5\linewidth}{!}{%
\smartdiagramset{
bubble node size =3.5cm, 
bubble center node font = \small,
bubble node font = \tiny, 
distance center/other bubbles = 1cm, 
}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{Traffic Flow\\ Problem,Neuroscience,Computer\\Science,Economics,Mathematics,Engineering, Physics}
}%end resizebox
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\resizebox{.5\linewidth}{!}{%
\smartdiagramset{
bubble node size =3.5cm, 
bubble center node font = \small,
bubble node font = \tiny, 
distance center/other bubbles = 1cm, 
set color list = {red!60, yellow!60, orange!60, green!60, purple!60, cyan!60}
}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{Traffic Flow\\ Problem,Neuroscience,Computer\\Science,Economics,Mathematics,Engineering, Physics}
}%end resizebox
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are quite a few unwanted white spaces by line ends in both the MWE and package `smartdiagram`.

Sometimes it helps, if the line ends are disabled, which can be achieved by `\endlinechar=-1`. However some packages break (e.g.,`tikz`), thus the example loads the package that are required by `smartdiagram` beforehand.

Also some line ends in the MWE are commented and `\box` is inserted to show the bounding box for the graphics.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% packages loaded by "smartdiagram"
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
   calc,
   fadings,
   shadows,
   shapes.arrows,
   shapes.symbols
}
\edef\RestoreEndlinechar{%
  \endlinechar=\the\endlinechar\relax
}
\endlinechar=-1
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\RestoreEndlinechar

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{%
    \resizebox{.5\linewidth}{!}{%
      \smartdiagramset{
        bubble node size =3.5cm, 
        bubble center node font = \small,
        bubble node font = \tiny, 
        distance center/other bubbles = 1cm, 
      }%
      \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
        Traffic Flow\\Problem,
        Neuroscience,
        Computer\\Science,
        Economics,
        Mathematics,
        Engineering,
        Physics%
      }%
    }% end resizebox
  }% end \fbox
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{%
    \resizebox{.5\linewidth}{!}{%
      \smartdiagramset{
        bubble node size =3.5cm, 
        bubble center node font = \small,
        bubble node font = \tiny, 
        distance center/other bubbles = 1cm, 
        set color list = {red!60, yellow!60, orange!60, green!60, purple!60,
            cyan!60}
      }%
      \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
        Traffic Flow\\Problem,
        Neuroscience,
        Computer\\Science,
        Economics,
        Mathematics,
        Engineering,
        Physics%
      }%
    }% end resizebox
  }%end \fbox
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]